# Выделение всего текст внутри тэга pre

Tags: html, css

Возможно ли по даблклику мыши выделять весь блок текста, обёрнутый в `<pre>`?

По умолчанию выделяется только 1 линия.

Тэг `<pre>` идеально подходит, т.к. им формируются куски конфигов для оборудования, а форматирование важно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться событием [dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) и проверить target, отвечая выделением в случае успеха:

```js
document.body.addEventListener("dblclick", event => {
  const target = event.target || event.srcElement
  if (target.className.indexOf("select-all") !== -1 || 
  target.parentNode.className.indexOf("select-all") !== -1) {
    let range
    let selection
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      range = document.body.createTextRange()
      range.moveToElementText(target)
      range.select()
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection()
      range = document.createRange()
      range.selectNodeContents(target)
      selection.removeAllRanges()
      selection.addRange(range)
    }
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
})
```

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre class="select-all">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</pre>
```

Comment: зачем что-то проверять, если можно повесить обработчик сразу на нужный элемент?